# Riemann Sum, Trapezoidal rule in C

Tags: c, function, loops, math, area

I've been trying to write a program that solves the area under a curve in C by using the Trapezoidal rule. The problem is, I think my logic is ok, I've review many times the algorithm and I can't still find the error.

In this was something assigned by my professor and he doesn't want us to use array, that's why you won't see any.

It scans func,a, p, q, err, where func is the function that will be used(function #1 or #2, but I've only done the #1),a is a constant, p is the initial x, q is the final x, and err is the margin of error, I think.

the program will divide the interval and calculate areas until last calculation of Area - total area we just calculates equals less than 10^-err

EDIT:I've made a few changes thanks to LutzL

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double F1(double x,double a){
    double f1=0.0;
    f1=(sqrt(a-pow(x,2)));
    return f1;
}

int main(){
    double a=0.0,p=0.0,q=0.0,h=0.0,x=0.0,err=0;
    int func=3,n=2;
    double power=0.0,T=0.0;
    double sum=0.0,last=0.0,difference=1.0;

    scanf("%d",&func);

    while(func!=0){
        n=2;
        scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf",&a,&p,&q,&err);
        power=pow(10.0,-err);
        h=(q-p)/n;

        if(func==1){
            difference=1.0;
            while(difference>=power){
                h=(q-p)/n;
                sum=0.0;
                for(x=p+h;x<=q-h;x++){
                    sum+=(2*F1(x,a));
                }
                T=(h/2)*(F1(p,a)+F1(q,a)+sum);
                if(difference==1.0){
                    difference=T;
                }else{
                    difference=last-T;
                }
                last=T;
                n++;
                }
        }
    printf("%.5lf\n",T);
    scanf("%d",&func);
    }
return 0;
}
```

The error is when I input 1, 4, -2, 1, 9. It should output 5.05481, but instead, it outputs 4.59808.

Comment: What doesn't it do that it is supposed to do? What is the error/problem?

Comment: What's the question?  What's the error?  Your implementation is less useful than it could be because you have all the code in a main method instead of a function that could be called in multiple places.

Comment: You need to reset `sum` to `0` between each attempt.

Comment: You need to recalc `h` when changing  `n`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie when I input 1, 4, -2, 1, 9. It should output 5.05481, but instead, it outputs 4.59808.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

`sum` should add the function values for the arguments from `p+h` to `p+(n-1)*h=q-h`, that is, `n-1` function values. At the moment you add `n` function values.

You do not double `n` inside the loop.

The best implementation uses midpoint sums

```
M(k)= f(p+h/2)+f(p+3h/2)+...+f(p+(2n-1)*h/2)
```

where `n=2^k, h=(q-p)/2^k`.

Then the trapezoidal sums

```
T(k)=0.5*f(p)+f(p+h)+...+f(p+(n-1)*h)+0.5*f(q)
```

satisfy the recursion

```
T(k+1) = T(k) + M(k)
```

with `T(0)=(f(p)+f(q))/2`. The integral approximations are of course `T(k)*(q-p)/2^k`.

Comment: thank you so much! I made those changes and now I'm closer to get the right output